# WebSocket connection to 'ws://X.XXX.XXX.XXX:5858/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to solve this issue since a long but not getting an accurate answer on the stackoverflow.

We are checking on this URL.
http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/v1/

and getting the following error.
Connecting to: http://x.xxx.xxxx.xxx:5858/ with options: {"path":"","transports":["websocket"]}

Here is the code snippet.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5858;
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Socket connection for Drivers
    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.room); // join room
        console.log('New user joined on room:' + data.room);
        console.log(data);
    });

 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Socket Listening on Port: ' + port);
});
```